# Will site load quicker if all CSS is in one stylesheet (as oppose to multiple stylesheets)

Tags: css, performance

I have one CSS stylesheet for all my styles and an additional CSS stylesheet for my @font-face stuff (I'm self-hosting some fonts). Would there be a performance advantage to combine these two stylesheets into one?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question! Yes it will be slightly quicker to have less CSS stylesheets. See https://varvy.com/pagespeed/combine-external-css.html

Answer (score 0):

it depends on your case

1) you can have all css in one big file, e.g. every media-query
2) but you can split it and load just the media-query needed

you have to calculate and test, what is better for you.. more data-volume or more requests

Answer (score 0):

This question is more complex than yes or no and depends on a whole lot of unspecified factors.

The first thing to note is that performance on the front-end has allot to do with how the user perceives the page to be loading.

It is generally a good idea to load styles for above the fold content in an inline block at the top of the DOM.

```
<style>
nav{
//Some navigation styles for example
}
</style>
```

This will get styled content on the page faster than loading the styles in a stylesheet with the rest of the styles.

Loading the stylesheets from two different links can be faster, if they come from two different domains. To read more about how browsers handle maximum concurrent connections, see: http://sgdev-blog.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/maximum-concurrent-connection-to-same.html

However, this depends on how many resources you are loading from your current domain.